# Angular 6, how to change style (rotate, colour, scale) of img based on variables (continuous change)

Tags: css, angular

In Angular to change the styling of an element or component I understand there are tools available in the form of directives (`ngStyle, ngClass`).  However as far as I can tell, `ngClass` allows for conditional styling only in which one changes styling based on a particular scenario.  These are therefore changes based on discrete conditions.

`ngStyle` allows an object to be passed which can in theory do this by returning a style object which is custom defined, but then `ngStyle` is listening perpetually to page changes, whereas I wish to trigger the style change when a specific action occurs, instead of listening to all page changes if possible?

I would like to programmatically change an images's css properties programmatically (rotation, width, height, opacity) based on perhaps a button press, or a mouse event, or just when a function is called, but the key is I want those changes to be continuous, for example, a rotation based on a variable in the component class, no discrete options of class changes.

In Angular, how would this be done?  `ViewChild` allows access to the DOM and therefore the styling, but the styles are read-only it would seem as they are computed.

I can't post code, as I don't know where to start to make such a thing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but then ngStyle is listening perpetually to page changes, whereas I wish to trigger the style change when a specific action occurs, instead of listening to all page changes if possible?

That's the whole point of Angular: you bind data to the view via a declarative template syntax it offers, and let it figure out when to update.

If you try to trigger update by manually knowing when data changes, you're probably doing something wrong (or you're optimizing a specific part of the library). Letting Angular do the update is the correct thing to do.

```
update () {
  this.styles = { /* ... */ }
}

<div [ngStyle]="styles">...</div>
```